# C++20 coroutines and happens-before relation

Tags: c++, c++20

Do C++20 coroutines provide some guarantees about synchronizes-with relation?
I would hope for something more or less like ``suspension synchronizes-with resumption" but that's probably too much. So far I was only able to find this statement on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines)

> Note that because the coroutine is fully suspended before entering awaiter.await_suspend(), that function is free to transfer the coroutine handle across threads, with no additional synchronization. For example, it can put it inside a callback, scheduled to run on a threadpool when async I/O operation completes.[...]

I also found this in [[coroutine.handle.resumption]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/coroutine.handle#resumption)

> Resuming a coroutine via resume, operator(), or destroy on an execution agent other than the one on which it was suspended has implementation-defined behavior unless each execution agent either is an instance of std​::​thread or std​::​jthread, or is the thread that executes main.
> [ Note: A coroutine that is resumed on a different execution agent should avoid relying on consistent thread identity throughout, such as holding a mutex object across a suspend point.
> — end note
> ]
> [ Note: A concurrent resumption of the coroutine may result in a data race.
> — end note
> ]

I also realize that the linked documentation of `handle.resume()` does not say that it happens-after some other operation. But still, the quoted statements seem to indicate that there are some synchronization guarantees, when
we pass the handle between different `std::thread`s. So what exactly is guaranteed? [Some links to relevant fragments of the standard for further reading will be deeply appreciated.]

Comment: A coroutine has nothing to do with multi threading. It is more or less only some syntactic sugar to let you interrupt a given thread of execution and do something meanwhile and keep the state of "current execution". But nothing works here parallel. You get only some hooks where you can switch the point of execution and back. In fact not more than a kind of full linear state machine which can be triggered to do some work while the caller waits.

Comment: OK, I do realize that. But when you pass the handle between threads, you have multi-threading :) And, if I'm not mistaken, the statements I quoted, seem to indicate that C++20 provides some synchronization guarantees in that case.

Comment: Yes, thats also my understanding. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines provides an example for that

Comment: @Klaus, Thanks, I've seen this example, but there we have actaully explicit sychchronization in await_susspend() by means of std::jthread constructor, so I still don't see what they mean by 'no additional synchronization'.

Comment: The "no additional synchronization" line refers to https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await#synchronisation-free-async-code

Comment: @Adrian: If some function A calls another function B which does synchronization, is it A doing the synchronization or is it B?

Comment: @Adrian: "*But still, the quoted statements seem to indicate that there are some synchronization guarantees*" How? There's nothing there about synchronization at all. Merely that if your threads are created by something outside of the standard thread library's purview, then how coroutine resumption works on such threads is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Sure, I can be misinterpreting this statement, but this is essentially what I'm asking. Are there some synchronization guarantees for e.g. coroutine-state in other parts of the standard, or not? Maybe, the statement just means that "if the programmer uses std::thread with handle.resume() always surrounded by 
my_std_mutex.lock()/unlock()  then everything is well defined". So, does it mean just that? BTW, unfortunately I don't understand your other comment with A/B functions. What are you saying there?

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks, this is a nice link, and it indeed provides expanded version of the quoted cppreference section. But I'm trying to understand how this "no need for additional synchronization" works in terms of C++ memory model. Does it mean that  any changes to coroutine-state made by the thread that suspended the coroutine are visible to the thread that calls handle.resume()? Or maybe the visibility must be ensured by us?

Comment: @Adrian: "*BTW, unfortunately I don't understand your other comment with A/B functions. What are you saying there?*" You were saying that resuming a coroutine involves synchronization because you can write a coroutine resumption function that creates a `std::thread`. Function A being to resumption and function B being the thread constructor. The resumption does not *inherently* synchronize anything; if there is synchronization, it is only because a *particular implementation* of resumption calls a function that does synchronization.

Comment: @Adrian: "*So, does it mean just that?*" It doesn't mean anything remotely like that. It says *nothing at all* about `thread` constructors, destructors, or anything remotely related to synchronization. It is purely talking about whether a coroutine gets resumed on a thread that was created *previously* by a standard library thread object. Specifically, it says that if you use a 3rd party library to create threads, and you resume a coroutine on such a thread, it's up to the implementation what the state of things are.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Thanks a lot! I thought that "no additional synchronization"  from cppreference.com means something like "some changes to the coroutine-state made by the std::thread that suspended the coroutine will be automatically visible to the thread that resumes it". And maybe this is a stupid "is the comment really says what it says" sort of question, but just to be sure: you are saying that to avoid data races on e.g. coroutine local variables the programmer must explicitly enforce that the call to `handle.resume()` happens-after we have entered `awaiter.await_suspend(handle)`, correct?